# how to send email without smtp python

Tags: python, email

I have an app that sends stock market price alerts via email. The way i designed it was that i created a yahoo low security account, and the app logs into that via smtp and then sends an email to a registered email address of the users...which can be many and scattered globally. The problem is that yahoo suddenly started to give me this error:

raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'6.6.0 Error sending message for delivery.')

my app creates two security problems.

1. People from all over the world might be using it.
   The app logs into a central email address, and sends from there email alerts to each users email address which they would have registered priorly.
2. the email alerts might be frequent depending on price movement.

both of these , are not liked by gmail or yahoo...

I would appreciate it, if someone can suggest ways around this security nonsense.

Is there a library I could use..or some sort of API, that could help me bypass the above issues.

Thank you

Comment: In short: Most likely you will likely need to run your own mailserver, or require that users specify their own mailserver and account to send mail from (i.e. their own GMail/Yahoo account or whatnot)

Comment: as it is now, they register their email and the app takes that and sends them from a central alerts@yahoo.com mail. ...do you mean, to specify they own GMAIL/yahoo username and password, so that the app can automatically get into their email and send an email to themselves? thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be one possibility. Another would be to operate a real mailserver on your end, handling outbound mail only (or mostly outbound mail).

Comment: Is that something that can be done easily?....can I do that with hmailserver??...I keep reading that it is only for local emailing and I am getting confused....how would I get my mail server created with hmailserver to send an email to you for example?

Comment: If you set up DNS properly it would suffice for remote emailing. I would just recommend asking users to provide their own outbound email account for now as it's far more simple.